# How to get `main` object evaluated in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, eval

How to know or get `main`, mean top-level binding, object evaluated in Ruby?

#### Example:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> self
=> main
irb(main):002:0> eval "self"
=> main
irb(main):003:0> eval "main"
NameError: undefined local variable or method `main' for main:Object
        from (irb):3:in `eval'
        from (irb):3:in `eval'
        from (irb):3
    from /home/malo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

The main constraint is that the code word shell be evaluated from anywhere, from within a class, module or instance. So it shall be universal.

Comment: What is the `main` code word? What is a code word, anyway?

Comment: downvoter: how can I improve question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To gain access to the "main" object from anywhere, use the `TOPLEVEL_BINDING`:

```
class MyShell
  def main_object
    TOPLEVEL_BINDING.eval('self') #=> "main"
  end
end
```